# Rounding the corners of the text (without using a specific font)

Tags: html, css

How to round the corners of the text (without using a specific font or size)?
I am trying to achieve the following:

[image]

Comment: highly doubt you are doing that with html and css....

Comment: @epascarello Are you talking about the image I put or in general that this cannot be achieved with CSS?

Comment: You can try [OpenType.js](https://opentype.js.org/). But forget doing it with only CSS

Comment: @complex_stock you don't have such a control with CSS

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina I'm not sure you're right,I found a kind of solution, but it only works for large text, and I need relatively small text https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710821/rounded-edges-on-fonts-with-css

Comment: @complex_stock in your link, you can play around and make `stdDeviation` and 35 smaller and the -7 as well and change the font size in CSS.

Comment: @complex_stock that's SVG. You need a way to convert your font to SVG first